# How to visualize an interaction term of a panel model in r?

Tags: r, visualization, regression, panel-data, plm

I aim to visualize an interaction term of a fixed effect model. I tried the packages 'visreg' and 'ggplot2', but it seems not possible.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Example dataset and panel model:

```
library(plm)
data(EmplUK)

m1 <- plm(emp ~ wage + capital + lag(output,1) + capital:lag(output,1), 
          data = EmplUK, model="within", effect="twoway", index=c("firm","year"))
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "visualizing the conditional effects"? Do you want to visualize the fit of the model to the data? The year fixed effects? The firm fixed effects?

Comment: @RoyalTS - Sorry for being unclear, I would like to visualize the interaction term (capital:lag(output,1)).

Comment: In case someone is interested: I used the linear model (lm) and added dummies for the id variable. The visualization using 'visreg' is fine.

Answer (score 1):

In the current CRAN-version of [sjPlot](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjPlot/index.html), the `sjp.int` function does not support `plm` objects.

However, I`ve implemented it in the current [GitHub-version](https://github.com/sjPlot/devel).

Taking your example from above, the following code:

`sjp.int(m1)`

produces following plot:

[image]

I'm not sure whether all kind of designs / models fitted with `plm` do work with `sjp.int`, if you find any bugs, feel free to file an issue ([at GitHub](https://github.com/sjPlot/devel/issues)).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the package here comes in handy? http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/sjp.int/

Also the `probemod` package from CRAN could help.